# python library to generate all factors of an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I tried `sympy.factorint()` but it returns a dictionary of prime factors with count.
I need all factors in a list in ascending order.

```
import sympy
sympy.factorint(567)
```

output

```
{3: 4, 7: 1}
```

I am looking for output like this

```
[1, 3, 7, 9, 21, 27, 63, 81, 189, 567]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution I should use `sympy.divisors()` instead

```
import sympy
sympy.divisors(n)
```